# SQL query to select a word from 100 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, substring

I have 100 columns in an Oracle table like this `Sh. North Miladhunmadulu - Shaviyani Atoll` . I need a query to select only `Shaviyani` from the above. Please help me. I need to select data after `-` and before `Atoll` word.

Comment: Do you actually mean "rows"  ( not "columns") when you're referring to 100?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: yes 100 rows of data in this column with like names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about rows and not column. You can achieve this using multiple comma separated CTE.

Below query has 3 cte table. Table `t0` will pull the position of the `'-'` using `charindex` function. Then using the charindex function we can find the  next space which should be after the word `Shaviyani`. As you can see there is immediate space after `'-'`. Therefore we will have added +2 to t0.position to the table `t1` which is used to find the position of the next space. The table `t3` will get the final result using `substring` function.

```
declare @string nvarchar(50)='Sh. North Miladhunmadulu - Shaviyani Atoll';

with t0 AS (select charindex('-',@string) pos, @string name),
     t1 AS (select charindex(' ',@string,pos+2) pos,name from t0),
     t2 AS (select substring(@string,t0.pos+1,t1.pos - t0.pos) name
            from t0
            inner join t1 on t0.name = t1.name )

select * from t2
```

**Output**

```
name
--------------------------------------------------
 Shaviyani
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working, i have like this data  in different tables. how to select based on column name from different columns.                                                                                        K. Male - Kaafu Atoll
S. Addu - Seenu Atoll
K. Male - Kaafu Atoll
K. Male - Kaafu Atoll
AA. North Ari - Alif Alif Atoll

Comment: I have using variable.  you can directly mention table name. for example, with t0 AS (select charindex('-',column.name) pos, column.name from table),

Comment: How does an answer that doesn't work in Oracle get accepted, much less upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` as following

```
SELECT SUBSTR('Sh. North Miladhunmadulu - Shaviyani Atoll',instr ('Sh. North Miladhunmadulu - Shaviyani Atoll','-')+1,
        ((instr ('Sh. North Miladhunmadulu - Shaviyani Atoll','Atoll')-1) - instr ('Sh. North Miladhunmadulu - Shaviyani Atoll','-'))) as OUTPUT
    FROM dual;
```

Here is output at [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36236b/1)

Replace the string by column name and `dual` with your table name.

Comment: after replacing the string by column name and dual with your table name. it is not working. column name is "address" and table name is "mydata"

Comment: Have you checked the example at Fiddle attached in answer?

Comment: At the very least, this runs in Oracle.